# Sort file by two column in the event of two the same value

Tags: bash, sorting

I want to sort files by one column, but in the event of two the same value I want to sort these two by other column. How can I do it?

My file:

```
1   2   3
1   3   2
1   4   3
2   4   1
2   1   3
3   1   4
3   1   2
```

I don't know I understand it right. After -k I type in column and options. Next option -k sort columnt, which are the same in first option k. Opcion -k 2 sort by second column and then by next one to the last or first column? -k 2,2 sort by second column and not sort others?

Comment: with the `-k` option for [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html). Scroll down to see several relevant examples.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: My command: sort -k 2 -r -k 1 -nf file
But it doesn't sort as second fist columnt not third(; is break line):
2 4 1;
1 4 3;
1 3 2;
1 2 3;
3 1 4;
3 1 2;
2 1 3;

Comment: I don't know I understand it right. After -k I type in column and options. Next option -k sort columnt, which are the same in first option k.
Opcion -k 2 sort by second column and then by next one to the last or first column? -k 2,2 sort by second column and not sort others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put several -k so it sorts using the first -k and in case of draw use the next -k .

In you example (sort -k 2 -r -k 1 -nf) it did what you asked: sort in reverse order by column 2 and in case of draw, by column 1 in ascending order. You can let option with the column name to be sure which option applies to which column. Your example could be sort -k 2nr -k 1n .

the -k 2,4 option tells sort to use columns 2 to 4 as a key to sort.